# How to remove unused shortcodes from wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have a quite few shortcodes that I no longer use. Below are the unwanted shortcodes that my site is currently showing for the frontend users all are visual composer plugin shortcodes.

1. [vc_row][vc_column width=”1/6″ offset=”vc_hidden-sm vc_hidden-xs”][/vc_column][vc_column width=”2/3″][vc_column_text]
2. [/vc_column_text][vc_column_text]

I want all of them to go. Hence, I found this code snippet as a result of my research. However, the created function will remove all of the shortcodes along with the active ones.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'mte_remove_unused_shortcode');
function mte_remove_unused_shortcode($content)
{ $pattern = mte_get_unused_shortcode_regex();
$content = preg_replace_callback( '/'. $pattern .'/s', 'strip_shortcode_tag', $content );
return $content; 
}
 
function mte_get_unused_shortcode_regex() {
 global $shortcode_tags;
$tagnames = array_keys($shortcode_tags);
$tagregexp = join( '|', array_map('preg_quote', $tagnames) );
$regex = '\[(\[?)';
$regex .= "(?!$tagregexp)";
$regex .= '\b([^\]\/]*(?:\/(?!\])[^\]\/]*)*?)(?:(\/)\]|\](?:([^\[]*+(?:\[(?!\/\2\])[^\[]*+)*+)\[\/\2\])?)(\]?)';
return $regex; 
}
```

How can I clean only the unused codes from the front end of my site? What am I doing wrong with the above code? I have tried it with the regex.

Comment: What is the contents of `$shortcode_tags;`? Did you try changing `$regex .= "(?!$tagregexp)";` to `$regex .= "(?:$tagregexp)";`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird It means content for shortcodes and filter shortcodes through their hooks. ... If there are no shortcode tags defined, then the content will be returned. No, I will try changing the regex.